# Which other domain does android.stackexchange.com use?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

In Firefox browser, I use uBlock Origin to limit 3rd party tracking.

When I login here, I get the message: "Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load."

Please state specifically what the other domain is that I need to open in order for this site to work (without habving to turn of uBlock origin altogether).

P.S. I have already allowed stackoverflow.com, same message appears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must at least permit `stackexchange.com` and `stackoverflow.com`. Probably also `sstatic.net` and `ajax.googleapis.com`. Those are the four I whitelisted for Android.SE. It also asks for `googletagservices.com` and `google-analytics.com`. The last one at least can be safely left out. Then there's `googleusercontent.com` which it most likely requires as well (else I hadn't whitelisted that).

Funnily, fewer of those are required for Meta …

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @bobn if that solved your issue, don't forget to "accept" the answer (ticking the check-mark next to it) to indicate so to other users :)

Comment: I'll have to be at home to try it.  won't be there for a while.

Comment: No prob, @bobn – just don't forget then :)

Comment: Addkin ajax.googleapis.com did it.  Thanks. 

Just as a note, *not* having google follow me around the internet is part of why I installed uBlock Origin in the first place.  It's a shame that eveybody can't host all the pieces of code that make their websites work.

(Not that I really mind google knowing I'm at stackexechange, it's the principle of the thing.)

Comment: My feelings exactly. One can *partly* work around that using [Decentral Eyes](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/decentraleyes/) (which provides the most common scripts like JQuery locally and rewrites the page code accordingly – would fit here as ajax.googleapis.com is mainly referenced for JQuery). You could give that a try. // Sidenote: On all of my web sites I take care to use external resources as little as possible. Especially no JavaScript from the "outer world".